# Pure Javascript YAML library that supports both dump and load?

Tags: javascript, serialization, markup, yaml, parsing

Does such a thing exist for [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml) (aka [YAML](http://yaml.org))?

If this existed at one time, it must have been obliterated because the latest search turned up nada. It looks like there are plenty of implementations that **dump** from Javascript to YAML output only, but having trouble finding an implementation that supports both dump and load.

Is anyone working on such a thing ... or is the demand simply far too low for this.

Comment: See also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335804/javascript-yaml-parser/5536931

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly newer version of js-yaml here:

http://github.com/visionmedia/js-yaml

Comment: I just tried this - it supports a subset of YAML, which is undocumented.  The author told me he wrote it for a specific project, and it is not a "complete" parser by any means.  I tried some of the basic YAML documents from yaml.org spec, and it fails.  It's pretty hard to use if you don't know what subset it defines.

Comment: I have just released our js-yaml (for node.js) - javascript port of PyYAML parser (emitter will be later). You can install it with `npm install js-yaml`. Or help in development: https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml

Answer (score 8):

Was just looking for the same, here's a basic [Javascript-based YAML parser](http://refactormycode.com/codes/1045-js-yaml-parser) written by [Tj Holowaychuk](http://refactormycode.com/users/634) over at [refactormycode.com](http://refactormycode.com/). I'm duplicating it here to ensure it isn't lost, appears the JsYaml link on yaml.org has been broken a while. Haven't tested it yet.

```
;(function(){
  YAML = {
    valueOf: function(token) {
      return eval('(' + token + ')')
    },

    tokenize: function(str) {
      return str.match(/(---|true|false|null|#(.*)|\[(.*?)\]|\{(.*?)\}|[\w\-]+:|-(.+)|\d+\.\d+|\d+|\n+)/g)
    },

    strip: function(str) {
      return str.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/, '')
    },

    parse: function(tokens) {
      var token, list = /^-(.*)/, key = /^([\w\-]+):/, stack = {}
      while (token = tokens.shift())
        if (token[0] == '#' || token == '---' || token == "\n") 
          continue
        else if (key.exec(token) && tokens[0] == "\n")
          stack[RegExp.$1] = this.parse(tokens)
        else if (key.exec(token))
          stack[RegExp.$1] = this.valueOf(tokens.shift())
        else if (list.exec(token))
          (stack.constructor == Array ?
            stack : (stack = [])).push(this.strip(RegExp.$1))
      return stack
    },

    eval: function(str) {
      return this.parse(this.tokenize(str))
    }
  }
})()

print(YAML.eval(readFile('config.yml')).toSource())




// config.yml

---
  # just a comment
  list: ['foo', 'bar']
  hash: { foo: "bar", n: 1 }
  lib:
    - lib/cart.js
    - lib/cart.foo.js
  specs:
    - spec/cart.spec.js
    - spec/cart.foo.spec.js
    # - Commented out
  environments:
    all:
      options:
        failuresOnly: true
        verbose: false
```

Answer (score 6):

I update this question to give another solution that myself worked on: https://github.com/jeremyfa/yaml.js

It is a pure javascript port of [Symfony YAML Component](https://github.com/symfony/Yaml/) (YAML 1.2) and supports both loading and dumping. Hope this helps.

Comment: Where others failed at parsing nested arrays and objects, your library worked. Thanks for the development efforts!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where the "plenty of implementations" that support dump but not load are to be found - to the extent that JSON is a proper subset of YAML 1.2, I guess there might be plenty of those, but that subset makes for YAML that is not particular human friendly, especially for complex data structures.  Most of the links I have found are to github forks of JS-YAML that depend on node.js and/or only provide parsers.

Jeremy Faivre's [yaml.js](https://bitbucket.org/jeremyfa/yaml.js/src) on bitbucket implements both dump and load of YAML in standalone javascript (I found it from an [answer to a related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8439851/18829)).  It is not actively maintained, but seems to work fine for moderately complex YAML and/or javascript objects.

Answer (score 2):

[yaml-javascript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yaml-javascript) pretends to be both dumper and parser. Never tried.

Comment: Unfortunately, that project doesn't seem to go past pretend on output dumping. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 2):

There's also this [javascript-yaml-parser/](http://code.google.com/p/javascript-yaml-parser/)

See this question: [JavaScript YAML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335804/javascript-yaml-parser/5536931#5536931), Diogo Costa says:
*None of the javascript YAML parsers available satisfied my needs so I developed my own: It is available here:* http://code.google.com/p/javascript-yaml-parser/