# JavaScript YAML Parser

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, yaml

I am looking for a JavaScript YAML parser which converts the YAML into something usable within a HTML page. I've tried this version on Github (https://github.com/visionmedia/js-yaml) but it looks like it only works with node.js

Which libraries should I be using and is there any sample code to show example usage?

Comment: Which libraries have you tried? Don't make us guess. Also, what problems did you have with them?

Comment: I've recently been looking for a JavaScript YAML libary, too. And after a long search, I've concluded that currently there isn't one. At least no reasonable one that supports all current features. js-yaml seems to be the "best", but it requires node.js, which I didn't want to use in my case. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428364/pure-javascript-yaml-library-that-supports-both-dump-and-load

Comment: See also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428364/pure-javascript-yaml-library-that-supports-both-dump-and-load

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[JS-YAML](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) parser works in browser. Here is an online demonstration : https://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml. Though, it's primary goal is node.js, and browser version was done just for fun :)

Comment: When I load the browser version in Safari 5.1, I just get "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object" in the right hand side - so it's not clear how well this works.

Comment: Apparently there are some [issues with Safari and some versions of IE](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/issues/21) - it did work for me in recent Firefox. Seems like the problems are just the typical Javascript across multiple older browser kinds of things (e.g. Array.isArray not implemented in Safari/IE).

Comment: @AlexDupuy yes, it's first target platform is node.js. There are some browser shims, but not all.

Comment: @Vitaly is this still the best option? Do you ever see native YAML parsing happening in the browser?

Comment: @Nikos, at least it works in demo. But i don't know cases from real life, when you really need to load yamls to browser. If you receive data from server - you can convert those to json/json5/..., that will be more light & easy.

Comment: @Vitaly - I know this is an old thread, but there are emerging use cases where better "browser" support would be useful. CloudFlare workers provide backend functionality at the network edge, but they leverage newer browser tech... essentially service workers.

Comment: it depends on `fs` which will not run in browsers

Comment: A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyuri/5nf4rbo6/3/) that demonstrates how to use `js-yaml` ([unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com/js-yaml@4.1.0/dist/js-yaml.min.js)).

Answer (score 29):

Here is one that I found. Not sure of how much of the spec this meets, but it suited my needs.

https://github.com/jeremyfa/yaml.js

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is dependency-free, reasonably small and works - at least on all of my files.

Comment: Update: both http://nodeca.github.com/js-yaml/ (accepted answer) and https://github.com/jeremyfa/yaml.js (this answer) seem to work and have the features @FloLedermann describes (unless you need the `js/function` schema checks). The former -- the accepted answer -- currently has more recent activity and more stars.

Comment: JS-YAML sounds like the maintainers do not intend it for browser use. I read that as "avoid, avoid". They say themselves - don't expect support or fixes.

Answer (score 24):

sorry for answering an old post, but I bumped into the same problem as you.

None of the javascript YAML parsers available satisfied my needs so I developed my own:
It is available here: http://code.google.com/p/javascript-yaml-parser/

Hope it helps somebody :)

Cumps,
Diogo

Comment: +1 Great. I'll have to try it out as soon as I can!

Comment: +1. What features did you not find in js-yaml? https://github.com/visionmedia/js-yaml  (By the way, it seems someone has forked js-yaml, and added support for string literals, https://github.com/mcantelon/js-yaml/commit/a09a560413526c1dfc984b08513b7630a0e72613 )

Comment: (Or was it js-yaml's dependency (??) on Node.js that prevented you from using it?)

Comment: This library wasn't working on my test file using nested lists, the one at https://github.com/jeremyfa/yaml.js works ok and is also dependency-free

Comment: @FloLedermann can you add link to your test file?

Answer (score 7):

[js-yaml](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) works fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox on OSX. Here is an example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test js-yaml</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js-yaml/dist/js-yaml.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // YAML string to Javascript object
        var obj = jsyaml.load( 'greeting: hello\nname: world' );
        console.log( obj );

        // YAML file to Javascript object
        $.get( 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/js-yaml/c50f9936bd1e99d64a54d30400e377f4fda401c5/benchmark/samples/document_application2.yaml', function( data ) {
            var obj = jsyaml.load( data );
            console.log( obj );
        });

        // Huge YAML file (7.2 MB) to Javascript object
        $.get( 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/js-yaml/master/benchmark/samples/document_huge.yaml', function( data ) {
            var obj = jsyaml.load( data );
            console.log( obj );
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test js-yaml</h1>
<p><a href="https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml">https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```