# How to parse YAML in the browser?

Tags: javascript, parsing, browser, yaml

I would like to parse YAML in the browser. Ideally I'm looking for a browser-ready library. The ones I've found are not written to run in a browser (they make synchronous calls to `require()` or assume the existence of an `exports` variable).

Alternatively, I'll accept example code that shows how to load a YAML-parsing library into the browser via [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: Agreed. Found an in-browser example at https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/blob/master/README.md.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Similar question: [JavaScript YAML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335804/javascript-yaml-parser).

The most promising library that seems to work in the browser is [js-yaml](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/blob/master/README.md). A snippet from the project page for loading the library in HTML:

```
<script src="js-yaml.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var doc = jsyaml.load('greeting: hello\nname: world');
</script>
```

They claim to also support AMD loaders like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org).

Here is the "browserified" version of the library: [with comments](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/blob/master/dist/js-yaml.js) and [minified](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/blob/master/dist/js-yaml.min.js).

Comment: A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyuri/5nf4rbo6/3/) that demonstrates how to use `js-yaml` ([unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com/js-yaml@4.1.0/dist/js-yaml.min.js)).

Comment: this works for serialization (to string)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-yaml/4.1.0/js-yaml.min.js"></script>
<script>
const txt = jsyaml.dump(item)
</script>
```