# How to convert yaml file to json using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, yaml

I need to do yaml validation and avoid duplicate entry also.Input is yaml file imported received form user.

Kindly some one help me to resolve this?

---

```
receipt:     Oz-Ware Purchase Invoice
date:        2012-08-06
    customer:
       given:   Dorothy
       family:  Gale

    items:
       - part_no:   A4786
         descrip:   Water Bucket (Filled)
         price:     1.47
         quantity:  4

       - part_no:   E1628
         descrip:   High Heeled "Ruby" Slippers
         size:      8
         price:     100.27
         quantity:  1

         bill-to:  &id001
         street: |
            123 Tornado Alley
            Suite 16
         city:   East Centerville
         state:  KS

         ship-to:  *id001

         specialDelivery:  >
         Follow the Yellow Brick
         Road to the Emerald City.
         Pay no attention to the
         man behind the curtain.
    ...
```

Comment: What does a DOM manipulation library have to do with a `yaml` file?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-to-json

Comment: i am using jquery only , can you kindly provide me some js fiddle example

Comment: jQuery doesn't help. It doesn't know  `yaml`, it can only import your file using Ajax. You need to use another tool. The above npm package looks promising. Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335804/javascript-yaml-parser