# Convert json to yml with Gulp/Node

Tags: node.js, gulp, fs

Using gulp/node, how can I convert this JSON file into a YML file?

Starting file: **`config.json`**

```json
{
  ":hello_world": "Test",
  ":foo_bar": [
    "One.js",
    "Two.txt",
  ]
}
```

Desired output: **`config.yml`**

```yaml
:hello_world: Test 
:foo_bar:
- One.js
- Two.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**js-yaml**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml), which seems to be the most widely used / adopted, and also is officially recommended by [**yaml.org**](https://yaml.org/)

```sh
npm i js-yaml
```

Then you can read in the json file, parse with `safeLoad`, and then serialize with `safeDump` like this:

```
const { promises: fs } = require("fs")
const yaml = require('js-yaml');

(async function main() {

    try {

        let configJson = await fs.readFile("./config.json", "utf-8")
        let doc = yaml.safeLoad(configJson)
        let configYaml = yaml.safeDump(doc)
        await fs.writeFile("./config.yaml", configYaml, "utf-8")


    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

})()
```

#### Further Reading

- [JavaScript YAML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4335804/1366033)
- [How to convert JSON to YAML in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38781929/1366033)
- [Convert yaml to json using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36973736/1366033)

#### NPM Libraries

- [nodeca/**js-yaml**](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml) - 5,700 ⭐s
- [jeremyfa/**yaml.js**](https://github.com/jeremyfa/yaml.js) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yamljs)) - 796 ⭐s
- [eemeli/**yaml**](https://github.com/eemeli/yaml) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml)) - 298 ⭐s
- [coolaj86/**json2yaml**](https://github.com/coolaj86/json2yaml) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2yaml)) - 69 ⭐s

Answer (score 0):

Using node you can use this library to convert from JSon to yml

https://www.npmjs.com/package/yamljs