# Convert yaml to json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, yaml

I got this yaml file:

```
description:
  is_a: AnnotationProperty
  labelEN: description
  labelPT: descrição

relevance:
  is_a: AnnotationProperty
  domain: Indicator
  labelEN: relevance
  labelPT: relevância

title:
  is_a: AnnotationProperty
  labelPT: título
  labelEN: title
  range: Literal
```

and I need to convert it to json, so I can get something like this:

```
{
    "description": {
        "is_a": "AnnotationProperty",
        "labelEN": "description",
        "labelPT": "descrição"
    },
    "relevance": {
        "is_a": "AnnotationProperty",
        "domain": "Indicator",
        "labelEN": "relevance",
        "labelPT": "relevância"
    },
    "title": {
        "is_a": "AnnotationProperty",
        "labelPT": "título",
        "labelEN": "title",
        "range": "Literal"
    }
}
```

and save it in a js variable...

So, how can I do this?

Hey, please check link below for [YAML to JSON converter](https://www.yamlonline.com/)
https://www.yamlonline.com/

Comment: I've voted to reopen (probably not important, as it's an old question). tl:dr - the linked question is different. My interpretation of this Q is "convert YAML to JSON" without specifying why (although the example does then store it in a variable). 
The other question is "parse/load Yaml to an object in javascript" (specifically for use in browser).

Answer (score 33):

You can solve that with a simple javascript script running on node.

1. install node.js
2. install the [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml) package: `npm install js-yaml -g`

Then save this script into a file, and run it with node.js:

```
var inputfile = 'input.yml',
    outputfile = 'output.json',
    yaml = require('js-yaml'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    obj = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(inputfile, {encoding: 'utf-8'}));
// this code if you want to save
fs.writeFileSync(outputfile, JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is—unfortunately—nothing in the standard library in JavaScript that will do this for you.

It's possible to build your own, but it's a lot of work. You would have to build a parser and there are likely a lot of edge cases that you would have to solve for. It might be worth considering using a [third-party module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yamljs).