# Convert yaml to JSON returns ["object Object"]

Tags: node.js, json, yaml

I am building a backend service to convert YAML to JSON. However, it returns ["object Object"].

Postman post request in text: `name: wf1`

Code:
    import { safeLoad } from 'js-yaml'

```
app.post('/,
    function (req, res) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(safeLoad(req.body)))
}
)
```

Return `["object Object"]`

I expect it return JSON format of `name: wf1`.

Comment: Can you show the `safeLoad` function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973736/convert-yaml-to-json

Comment: @TsvetanGanev Yes, it's from `js-yaml`.

Comment: @NicolaeMaties I have read that answer but it does not answer my question because I get wrong result rather than I do not know how to get result.

Comment: So you're sending YAML in the request body? I'm not sure Express body-parser can parse this by default. Can you check what's the value of `req.body`?

Comment: you may get the object because the library you are using the receive the response is parsing the payload automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the body is actually parsed as raw text if you're intending to send text (i.e. Content-Type: text/plain) in your request. Using the `text`-[function](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparsertextoptions) from `body-parser` should fix this issue:

```
app.use(bodyParser.text())
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(safeLoad(req.body)));
})
```

Note that if you're intending to send actual json back to the client you need to change this to:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json(safeLoad(req.body));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml), `safeLoad` function only accept String as input type but `req.body` should return as a object. Maybe point to the particular key can work for you.