# How to convert JSON to YAML in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, yaml

I want to convert a json string to yaml format in javascript. I was searching on google for the last two days but couldn't find any solution or libraries.
There are answers available for java but not for javascript.

Suppose I have a json string like this:

```
{
  "json": [
    "fat and rigid"
  ],
  "yaml": [
    "skinny and flexible"
  ],
  "object": {
    "array": [
      {
        "null_value": null
      },
      {
        "boolean": true
      },
      {
        "integer": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

converted to yaml:

```
json:
  - fat and rigid
yaml:
  - skinny and flexible
object:
  array:
    - null_value:
    - boolean: true
    - integer: 1
```

There is an online converter http://www.json2yaml.com/ , but how can I convert to it in javascript?

Comment: YAML is a superset of JSON: any valid JSON is also valid YAML; you may not need to convert anything.

Comment: Google 'npm Json to yaml'. There's over a half-dozen libraries.

Comment: @Jacob thanks you, can you please add it as answer so that if anyone coming to see a proper answer get benefit or save their day?

Comment: Deleted my answer because it was collecting so many downvotes. I stand by it though. If you have code that requires a YAML input and you have JSON instead, you don't have to convert the JSON to YAML. That's a legitimate case where you don't need to convert. If you solely want to convert because you prefer the syntax (why?!) see these other solutions.

Answer (score 25):

You can use [yaml](https://github.com/eemeli/yaml) NPM package.

```js
const YAML = require('yaml');

const jsonObject = {
    version: "1.0.0",
    dependencies: {
        yaml: "^1.10.0"
    },
    package: {
        exclude: [ ".idea/**", ".gitignore" ]
    }
}

const doc = new YAML.Document();
doc.contents = jsonObject;

console.log(doc.toString());
```

Output

```yaml
version: 1.0.0
dependencies:
  yaml: ^1.10.0
package:
  exclude:
    - .idea/**
    - .gitignore
```

Comment: The `YAML` package now includes a `stringify()` method, so you can just do `YAML.stringify(jsonObject)` to get the same result. See docs [here](https://eemeli.org/yaml/#yaml-stringify).

Answer (score 21):

You can use the '[js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml)' npm package. It is officially recognized by yaml.org.

To then generate a YAML string from an object, you can use the following method:

```
yaml.dump(JSON.parse("yourJsonString"));
```

The full documentation for this method is available here: [dump()](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml#dump-object---options-).

Comment: can you please add an example of how to parse with js-yaml, i tried to use yaml.parse() but it's deprecated..

Comment: To save everyone 5m, and to answer @omer. json string to yaml string: `yaml.dump(<your object>)`

Comment: Make sure you are passing an object to `dump` function (not string – in my case I had to use `dump(JSON.parse(...))`)

Comment: What's the difference between `js-yaml` and `yaml`? I see this one has twice the weekly downloads, but hasn't been updated in 2 years.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to package the answer to a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#convert-json-to-yaml.sh

if [[ "$1" == "" ]]; then
    echo "You must provide a json file in argument i.e. ./convert-json-to-yaml.sh your_file.json"
    exit 1
fi

jsonFile=$1
yamlFile="$1.yaml"

if [[ "$2" != "" ]]; then
    yamlFile=$2
fi

python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; yaml.safe_dump(json.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False)' < ${jsonFile} > ${yamlFile}
```

Comment: This is dope, going to try it out

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it :)

```
import * as YAML from 'yaml';
const YAMLfile = YAML.stringify(JSONFILE);
```

And if you want to create a YAML file, you do it with de FS.

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
fs.writeFileSync('./fileName.yaml', YAMLfile);
```