# How to convert a YAML file to Dockerfile

Tags: javascript, docker, yaml, serverless

Before describing the problem I need to give an overview of what I am doing:
I have to pass a JSON file containing base images and dependencies and generate a YAML file. I am able to generate the YAML file but the next step is to use the generated YAML file to make a docker file.

My idea:
Basically, dockerhub has all programs like pyhton3, java etc installed on library/docker and many other folders like that.

JSON file **sample.json** :

```
{
    "base_image" : "ubuntu",
    "dependency" : ["dependency1", "dependency2"]
}
```

My **handler.js** function for validating the json file (Here event is the JSON file) :

```
'use strict';
//const fs = require("fs")
module.exports.validate = (event, context, callback) => {

var JSONObject = JSON.parse(event.body);
var base_image = JSONObject.base_image;
var dependency = JSONObject.dependency;
if(base_image == "" || dependency == "")
{
  const response = {
    statusCode: 400,
    body: JSON.stringify({
    message: "false"
  })
  };
  callback(null, response);
}
else{
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
    message: true
  }),
  };

callback(null, response);
}

};
```

I have a YAML file **sample.yml** like :

```
---
  base_image : "ubuntu"
  dependency:
    - "dependency1"
    - "dependency2"
```

And I have to generate a docker file out of this. Is this possible?
If so how?

Plese note this is a POC and I am trying to make a serverless microservice that generates a dockerfile out of the json file given as input which contains base_image and dependencies.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT1:
I have already converted the JSON to YAML using npm install -g json2yaml. Now I have to use the YAML to autogenerate dockerfile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON to YAML in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781929/how-to-convert-json-to-yaml-in-javascript)

Comment: I want a dockerfile out of YAML, I have already done what you are suggesting.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand. But could you modify your question to remove js part? Suggest just a input yaml, and a output dockerfile you needed? Dockerfile has FROM, RUN, WORKDIR, ADD, CMD, ENTRYPOINT etc, how they define in your yaml? People need a mininal workable question then we can quickly help you. And also what you have tryied since now.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the look of output dockerfile, but to get a rough idea understand that I have to autogenerate a docker file that creates a docker image of java with dependencies as mentioned in the JSON file/As seen later in YAML also.

Comment: So let me understand your real aim: You want to a docker images base on ubuntu, and dependency maybe dynamic, based on yaml. If you specify `python`, `ssh`, then the dockerfile should automatically have `python`, `ssh` install steps. Then you can dynamic generate dockerfile, build it. Finally you have a image with python, ssh based on ubuntu?

Comment: Yes we may get different dependencies each time and we need to automatically generate a docker file, Which can be run to get the docker image

Comment: Let's say if we need `python` & `ssh`, what needed to be autogenerated in dockefile: `RUN apt-get install -y python`, `RUN apt-get install -y openssh`, the key is sometimes the name maybe not align with `dependency` and `apt package`, and also, for `ssh`, you may had  to add `service ssh start in entrypoint.sh file` for `CMD`, otherwise, the ssh-server will not be auto start in docker ubuntu image.

Comment: So many things need to do, unless your depenency is limited, just a few options, then you can `switch` with different dependency to add different `RUN` in dockerfile, then this is just a hardcoding script to handle all user options, I think you can do it, but a little tedious. But if you need purely dynamic dependcy automatially with code filled in dockerfile, I think you are meeting a big chanllenge, `A AI TASK`, I think.

Comment: You're correct, that becomes an AI task but for now I want to work out something for a limited dependencies and not dynamic dependencies. Can you suggest something for that?

Comment: A ugly solution, not know any better, see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dockerfile.template**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update

WORKDIR /root
ADD ./entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 775 ./entrypoint.sh
CMD ./entrypoint.sh
```

**entrypoint_template.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
```

You need write a script some logic as follows:

If dependency has `ssh`, add `apt-get -y install openssh` in `Dockerfile.template` after the line of `RUN apt-get update`, also add `service ssh start` in `entrypoint_template.sh` after `#!/bin/bash`

If dependency has `python` add `apt-get -y install python` in `Dockerfile.template` after the line of `RUN apt-get update`

Then after all dependency loop finish, add `tail -f /dev/null` to the end of `entrypoint_template.sh` if your last command not in front ground.

Finally change the `Dockerfile.template` to `Dockerfile`, and change `entrypoint_template.sh` to `entrypoint.sh`

This is a pure hard coding logic, but no methods unless you can have a AI method to simulate programmers to automatically write dockerfile for you for every scenario.