# Convert JSON to YAML with reference properties

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, yaml

I am building a web interface for configuring YAML files and therefore need to parse YAML to JSON and back to YAML. The node-module yaml-js does quite a good job converting my YAML to JSON but when I convert back to YAML the files end up huge and not really human-readable as duplicates are not saved as anchors and references. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is a minimal version of what I would like to achieve:

```js
const yaml = require("js-yaml");

const json = {
  constants: {
    person: {
      name: "july",
      id: 2
    }
  },
  worldObject: {
    name: "july",
    id: 2
  },
  worldArray: [
    {
      name: "july",
      id: 2
    },
    {
      name: "july",
      id: 2
    }
  ]
};

const jsonToYaml = async () => {
  const output = yaml.safeDump(json);
  console.log(output);
};

jsonToYaml();
```

#### Expected output

```yaml
constants:
    person: &person 
        name: july
    id: 2
worldObject: *person
worldArray:
- *person
- *person
```

Alternative: https://codesandbox.io/s/small-pine-0w4ze?file=/src/index.js

Huge thanks in advance!
Theo

Comment: You might need to use another package for converting JSON to YAML. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61852795/1762224 (`yaml` package).

Comment: See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml#caveats ~ _"Also, reading of properties on implicit block mapping keys is not supported yet. So, the following YAML document cannot be loaded."_

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Polywhirl . This approach though seems to create the same result. Still without YAML anchors for repeated objects. I tried it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wood-11me5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yes I am a bit confused because js-yaml gives the option {noRefs: false/true} which seems to turn off automatic reference creation. Maybe I am understanding something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the source JavaScript object (not JSON) has no concept of references. You are not converting a JavaScript object with nested references. You can only make use of YAML reference as long as your underlying JavaScript object has references.

Here is an example that provides your expected output:

```js
const yaml = require("js-yaml");

const person = {
  name: "july",
  id: 2
};

const obj = {
  constants: {
    person: person
  },
  worldObject: person,
  worldArray: [
    person,
    person
  ]
};

const jsonToYaml = async () => {
  const output = yaml.safeDump(obj);
  console.log(output);
};

jsonToYaml();
```

#### Output

```yaml
constants:
  person: &ref_0
    name: july
    id: 2
worldObject: *ref_0
worldArray:
  - *ref_0
  - *ref_0
```

You lose the concept of references, when moving strictly from JSON to YAML.

For the expanded object, you can pass `true` for `noRefs`.

```js
const output = yaml.safeDump(obj, { noRefs: true });
```

---

### An actual JSON example

As you can see in the example below, I am using actual JSON. As described above, once you deserialize the JSON into an object, you actually have no references.

```js
const yaml = require("js-yaml");

const jsonStr = `{
  "constants": {
    "person": {
      "name": "july",
      "id": 2
    }
  },
  "worldObject": {
    "name": "july",
    "id": 2
  },
  "worldArray": [ {
    "name": "july",
    "id": 2
  }, {
    "name": "july",
    "id": 2
  } ]
}`;

const jsonToYaml = async () => {
  console.log(yaml.safeDump(JSON.parse(jsonStr)));
};

jsonToYaml();
```

Comment: Great! This will do the job! Thanks a lot for taking your time! This is really clean!

Comment: @TheodorGoloHillmann glad to hear! Just keep in mind that JSON !== Object.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl  Is allowed to generate references for partial inheritance？

eg. 

```yaml
person: &ref_0
    name: july
    id: 2

person_1:
<<: *ref_0
    field_1: 1

person_2:
<<: *ref_0
    field_2: 2
```

Comment: @JianhuaCheng even am facing the same problem did you found any fix

Comment: @ksk I don't have a solution for this...Maybe the most feasible way is to manually do the transformation.