# Can/should I use YAML as payload in RESTful webservice?

Tags: json, web-services, rest, yaml

As the header says.

In general I like YAML more than JSON these days. I implemented a RESTful WS PoC back in the day using JSON. I was wondering if I can instead use YAML or not.

E.g. are there enough tools/libraries/support for doing that? Or would I end up doing quite a bit of mundane/tedious coding which I would've avoided if I were using JSON instead?

Also as I understood from WWW: REST doesn't restrict one from using YAML as the payload, is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You are correct. Don't know anyone who does it. I believe that yaml might be quite slow to parse, but could be wrong there.

Comment: You certainly *can*. There's no restriction on using any particular media type as the resource representation. You can represent anything with YAML that you can with JSON. Library support may indeed be much worse, though. Keep in mind though that to truly be RESTful, the API [must be hypertext-driven](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven), i.e., you can't just use `application/json` or `application/x-yaml`, since neither of those media types provide for hypertext. You'll need to define your own media type like `application/x-yaml+kashyapws` or what-not.

Comment: Why don't you use both? I guess some of your 3rd party clients like JSON, while others can use YAML if they prefer that one...

Comment: @Claudiu The vendor specific MIME type is about self-descriptive message, so if you don't use RDF and annotate your data with metadata, then you should use a vendor specific MIME type and document what each data property means. Still you need to send the hyperlinks in a header, or you need to create a WADL or WSDL file, since the links are not documented by the MIME type. Unless your vendor specific MIME type supports hyperlinks and you send hyperlinks with the response.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, if it's a goal that the data be especially readable by humans.  REST itself isn't focused on protocols/formats so much as patterns.

There's not a lot to gain here for webservices however, which typically represent app to app communication.  Computers don't care, and JSON can be pretty-printed to improve legibility somewhat.

YAML is well supported by mainstream languages, though not always included in standard libraries as JSON typically is.  So you'll probably be looking at an additional library dependency.
Also, if the client is a browser, parsing will be slower, as you'll have to use a non-native external lib such as described here using: [JavaScript YAML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4335804/450917) .  Make sure it gets compressed in transit or the extra indentation spaces will expand the size of the data.

Also, YAML has a lot of esoteric and downright potentially dangerous features.  Whenever I'm using it I use the "safe" parser, and deactivate many if not most of its features besides data structures.

I could imagine some utility as a debug parameter however, perhaps `url.yaml` or `…?fmt=yaml` to assist during development.  But otherwise not much gain for all the trouble.