# Can we include variable value from .yml in js for if else condition?

Tags: javascript, yaml

I need to access the variable value stored in .yml file, yes or no...
and on yes or no based I need to write js code. Please help with examples if you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript YAML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335804/javascript-yaml-parser)

Comment: Please note that since Sep 2006, according to the YAML FAQ on yaml.org, the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml`.