# How can I read data from YAML file (saved in my PC) in angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, yaml

I'm new to angular and web development. I want to get some data from YAML file into my angular application. The file contains meta-data for an image. How can I upload the YAML file so that I can read few values from YAML file. I need to get the value of resolution in my application.
Thank you.

```
image: logistikhalle5.png
resolution: 0.007
origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.000000]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.165
free_thresh: 0.001
```

Comment: Do you want your users to upload their yaml files or do you want all the users to read the yaml file that persists in your computer? Well, the latter one is a bit difficult, and you can understand why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript YAML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335804/javascript-yaml-parser)

Comment: I want  users to upload a png image and a yaml file associated to that png. Then I want to display him the image and its resolution value(which is in its yaml file). @CristianTraìna

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Angular's HttpClient Module](https://angular.io/guide/http) to request (more or less) any web resource. Besides you can load local resources from certain project directories like i. e. *assets*. Unfortunately, unlike e. g. the JSON format, you will have to *parse* your YAML files manually after retrieving the plain text.

As a starting point, you should also learn the basics about how to use [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables) and [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) (DI) in Angular. Observables are used to handle *asynchronous* tasks like HTTP requests, while DI helps you to create service instances that you can use in several components.

This example code provides a service named **YamlService**. Its `fetchYaml()` method will request a local resource from your *assets* directory and convert the plain text response into a simple JavaScript Object.

```
@Injectable()
export class YamlService {
  // the constructor injects the HttpClient service
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchYaml('example.yaml');
  }

  public fetchYaml(fileName) {
    // if you wonder about the string syntax, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
    this.http.get(`/assets/${fileName}`, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(response => {
      let lines: string[] = response.split('\n');  // create array where each YAML line is one entry
      let object = {};
      lines.forEach((line: string) => {
        let delimiter = line.indexOf(':');  // find the colon position inside the line string 
        let key = line.substr(0, delimiter - 1);  // extract the key (everything before the colon)
        let value = line.substr(delimiter + 1);  // extract the value (everything after the colon)
        object[key] = value;  // add a new key-value pair to the object
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You made this so simple for me to understand. It's working. Thank you very much.