# Js file formatting in json of the .ssh/config

Tags: javascript, json, file, serialization, format

I have the following file:

```yaml
# Personal account - default config
Host github.com-user1
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user1
# Official account
Host github.com-user2
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user2
```

I want it to become the following JSON:

```json
[
  {
    Host: 'github.com-user1',
    HostName: 'github.com',
    User: 'git',
    IdentityFile: '~/.ssh/id_rsa_user1'
  },
  {
    Host: 'github.com-user2',
    HostName: 'github.com',
    User: 'git',
    IdentityFile: '~/.ssh/id_rsa_user2'
  }
]
```

How many comments should be removed those starting with #, the name of the key would be the first element of the line, its value what is found after the space.

I wrote the following code, it works, but I would like to optimize it.
For example it doesn't take the last element inside the reduce, I had to insert it outside of it.

There may be other key values than the ones entered, such as the ForwardAgent, AddKeysToAgent, UseKeyChain.

The only certain thing is that each account must start from the Host key.

Can you give me a hand?

```js
import { exec as cExec } from "child_process";
import { promisify } from "util";

const exec = promisify(cExec);

  async function ssh() {
    const cmd = 'while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < "$HOME/.ssh/config"'
    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(cmd);
    if (stderr) throw new Error(stderr);

    const a = stdout.replace("\n", "");
    let obj = {};
    const b = stdout.trim().split("\n").reduce((r, a) => {
      if (!a.includes("#")) {
        let [name, value] = a.trim().split(" ");

        if (name === "Host") {
          if (Object.keys(obj).length > 0) r.push(obj);
          obj = {};
          obj[name] = value;
        } else {
          obj[name] = value;
        }

      }

      return r;
    }, []);

    if (Object.keys(obj).length > 0) b.push(obj);
    return b
  }
```

Comment: The end result you show is not valid JSON; In JSON the key must be surrounded with double quotes, as should string values. Are you just looking to parse the config file as objects, or do you actually need to store the JSON?

Comment: In either case, it seems like what you need is a library that will parse the format you're using to JavaScript objects, which can be trivially serialized to JSON using `JSON.stringify`. The format appears to be YAML, in which case, [a YAML to JSON library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4335804/215552) would fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to use an existing library for parsing ssh configs, like [ssh-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh-config).

The [ssh config format](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) is more complicated than you think. For example, some details you missed:

- keywords can be case insensitive
- `#` is only a comment if the line starts with it
- some keywords may have multiple quoted or space-separated arguments, not just 1 value
- the `Match` keyword also starts a new section, not just `Host`

The ssh-config library can handle that.

But since you asked about "reduce": *in the abstract*, if you were parsing a similar format which *does not* have a good existing library, the implementation could be structured like this:

```js
const content = fs.readFileSync(process.env.HOME + "/.ssh/config", "utf8");

const sections = [];
for (const line of content.trim().split("\n")) {
  if (line.trim() === "" || line.includes("#")) {
    continue;
  }
  let [name, value] = line.trim().split(" ");
  if (name === "Host" || sections.length === 0) {
    sections.push({});
  }
  sections[sections.length - 1][name] = value;
}

return sections;
```

Note that this code doesn't fix the above problems! It is just an example, you should still use a library!