# Javascript object serialize readable

Tags: javascript, serialization

How do I serialize a javascript object.

I've tried JSON.stringify, which is great, but it serializes into JSON, with quotes around all the keys.

I'm looking for something that's not going to give me quotes around keys and still produce something readable, with padding.

Thanks.

Comment: Uhm.... why? Is "not liking quotes around keys" the **only** reason you don't want to use JSON?

Comment: @Matt yes indeed, i think it looks messy

Comment: @Matt I want to emphasis that the point is not to get any useable or machine readable data, it's purely for display purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look into YAML. We here use YAML, but let me look into it more, to see whether I can cite you some example.

Go through this stackoverflow discussion: [Pure Javascript YAML library that supports both dump and load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428364/pure-javascript-yaml-library-that-supports-both-dump-and-load)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it looks cleaner, but actually more confusing what with the white space and all.

Comment: yup, it will make your serialized data "padded and readable", the thing is, it has to be! You will be uncomfortable in the beginning but you will get used to it.